# How do you pass php variable to python and print out below imports?

Tags: python, php

We have successfully passed value from our PHP here in this example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

print("We have successfully received: " + sys.argv[1])
```

But when we pass to our application and print below import it doesn't work.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import statsmodels.api as sm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from pandas.tseries import offsets
import warnings
import json
from pathlib import Path

print("We have successfully received: " + sys.argv[1])
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. We are stumped.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? And what does "it doesn't work" mean, _specifically_? Have you looked for error messages? Have you tried adding the "import" lines one at a time, to see if one in particular causes the error?

Comment: @IMSoP Just wanted to give the whole picture by mentioning PHP. I have tried outputting the print(sys.argv[1]) below each import. The print(sys.argv[1]) only works below "import sys". If placed below anything else it doesn't work. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: When you say "below anything else", do you mean you've only tried the imports _in that order_, or have you tried, for instance, just "import sys" and "import json", then the "print"? What about _just_ "import numpy as py" without the "import sys"? Also, how are you running this - I'm guessing that's where PHP comes in? Have you tried running it a different way, e.g. directly from a terminal?

Comment: If something stops working just because of an import, and you're not getting any error messages as a result of the new imports, the most likely scenario is that the thing that stops working got shadowed (redefined as something else with the same name) in one of the imports. Although that would be very unlikely for common and well-known libraries, to shadow something as basic as `sys` or `sys.argv` (or `print`). Do you get any feedback from the script? Error message, printed output, or just nothing?

Comment: I've just created a clean virtual environment based on Python 3.10 and installed all the packages you're importing - your code works as expected, so your problem cannot be reproduced. Please specify (in your question) what version of Python you are using, what operating system you're running on, what versions of packages you are running (run `pip freeze` and share output for example) and show how you actually call/test the script.

Comment: I have run with import numpy by itself and then print and it wont print. It only prints with import sys or just writing print by itself. Any import outside of import sys doens't allow me to print.***

In terminal everything works fine. When I pass from PHP to Python I can get the print two work exactly how I explained above***

***<?php

$python_param = "some variable value";

$get_python = escapeshellcmd("PATH=/usr/bin python3 /var/www/html/aps/cgi-bin/test.py ".$python_param);
$output = shell_exec($get_python);

echo $output;***

Comment: @Grismar 

// Server info
Python 3.6.8
PHP 8.0.14
Operating System: CentOS Linux 8
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)

Comment: @Grismar 
// Python pkgs w/versions
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
Babel (2.5.1)
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.3)
cffi (1.11.5)
chardet (3.0.4)
cloud-init (21.1)
configobj (5.0.6)
cryptography (3.2.1)
cssselect (0.9.2)
dbus-python (1.2.4)
decorator (4.2.1)
et-xmlfile (1.1.0)
gpg (1.13.1)
html5lib (0.999999999)
idna (2.5)
isc (2.0)
Jinja2 (2.10.1)
joblib (1.1.0)
jsonpatch (1.21)
jsonpointer (1.10)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
libcomps (0.1.16)
lxml (4.2.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
netifaces (0.10.6)
nftables (0.1)
numpy (1.19.5)
oauthlib (2.1.0)
openpyxl (3.0.9)
pandas (1.1.5)
patsy (0.5.2)

Comment: @Grismar 
// Python pkgs w/versions
pciutils (2.3.6)
perf (0.1)
pexpect (4.3.1)
pip (9.0.3)
ply (3.9)
prettytable (0.7.2)
psutil (5.4.3)
ptyprocess (0.5.2)
pyasn1 (0.3.7)
pycairo (1.16.3)
pycparser (2.14)
pydbus (0.6.0)
pygobject (3.28.3)
PyJWT (1.6.1)
pyOpenSSL (19.0.0)
pyserial (3.1.1)
PySocks (1.6.8)
python-dateutil (2.8.2)
python-dmidecode (3.12.2)
python-linux-procfs (0.6.3)
pytz (2017.2)
pyudev (0.21.0)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.20.0)
rhnlib (2.8.6)
rpm (4.14.3)
schedutils (0.6)

Comment: @Grismar 
scikit-learn (0.24.2)
scipy (1.5.4)
selinux (2.9)
sepolicy (1.1)
setools (4.3.0)
setroubleshoot (1.1)
setuptools (39.2.0)
six (1.11.0)
slip (0.6.4)
slip.dbus (0.6.4)
sos (4.1)
SSSDConfig (2.5.2)
statsmodels (0.12.2)
syspurpose (1.28.21)
systemd-python (234)
threadpoolctl (3.1.0)
urllib3 (1.24.2)
WALinuxAgent (2.5.0.2)
webencodings (0.5.1)
xlrd (1.2.0)
XlsxWriter (3.0.2)
xlwings (0.26.3)

Comment: @Grismar How the application works is that we have a PHP file that sends via jQuery an ID value. PHP gets that $POST value and sends it to a Python script that processes that ID and returns 1 or True.

Comment: @Grismar the hang up is that the ID or sys.argv[1] gets lost after the imports in that processing python file.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding information in the form of comments, it becomes an unreadable alphabet soup... You haven't really addressed my point though.  If you create a new Python virtual environment, and install the packages you need - it works without issue. So either the problem is with how you call the script (for which you provide no information), or the problem is with unrelated packages installed in your environment. You also haven't made clear how you can tell "it works" in the script without imports, and how you can tell it doesn't for the other?

Comment: FYI: I have a CentOS 7 with Python 3.6.8 and if I install your project requirements (just `sklearn`, `statsmodels` and `requests` and their dependencies) your script runs just fine without errors and with expected output. Your problem cannot be reproduced - more so because you say the script without imports does perform as expected, so it seems pointless to reproduce your PHP setup - there must be some issue in your environment, I recommend you do the same: set up a clean environment and test there.